# Given a random variable with probability density function f(x), how to compute the expected value of this random variable in R?

Tags: r

Given a random variable with probability density function f(x), how to compute the expected value of this random variable in R?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to compute the expected value, just compute :

E(X) = Integral of xf(x)dx over the whole domain of X.

The integration can easily be done using the function integrate().

Say you're having a normal density function (you can easily define your own density function) :

```
f <- function(x){
     1/sqrt(2*pi)*exp((-1/2)*x^2)
}
```

You calculate the expected value simply by:

```
f2 <- function(x){x*f(x)}
integrate(f2,-Inf,Inf )
```

Pay attention, sometimes you need to use Vectorize() for your function. This is necessary to get integrate to work. For more info, see the help pages of integrate() and Vectorize().

Comment: Why `Vectorize` is needed? `f2` is already vectorized function. Or I missed something?

Comment: In this case, it is. I just wanted to point out the obvious error when using integrate. I've seen it many times before. I'll correct

Answer (score 1):

Does it help to know that the expectation E is the integral of `x*f(x) dx` for `x` in `(-inf, inf)`?

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the [inverse sampling transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling). All you need is the cumulate density function F(x) of your random variable X. It utilises the fact that the random variable U = F(X) is uniform (with pdf f(x)). You then have that X = F^-1(U). This means that you can sample from a uniform variable and then transform it through F^-1(U) to get a sample from X. You can then take the mean of your sample.

Here is an example for the [exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution) distribution with parameter lambda = 5, mean = 1/5, F(x) = 1 - exp(-lambda * x) and F^-1(u) = -log(1 - x) / lambda.

```
sample_exp = function(n, lambda = 5){
  u = runif(n)
  y = -log(1 - u) / lambda
  mean(y)
}

n = seq(10, 4000, 10)
res = sapply(n, sample_exp)
plot(n, res, type = "l", xlab = "sample size",
     ylab = "Estimated mean", main = "True mean = 0.2")
```

Below is a plot of the estimated mean as a function of the sample size:

[image]